# Send Email With Attachment Flutter(IOS)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem when send email in flutter(**IOS**). I use flutter_email_sender lib.

```
Future<void> send() async {
    final Email email = Email(
      body: _bodyController.text,
      subject: _subjectController.text,
      recipients: [_recipientController.text],
      attachmentPath: attachment,
      isHTML: isHTML,
    );
    await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
  }

button... onPressed: send()
==> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(not_available, No email clients found!, null)
```

Comment: did you try that on the iOS emulator?

Comment: My problem is resolved. root cause is I forgot setting email in iOS. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on iOS. It was caused because iOS hadn't set up the default Mail Application. Did you setting it on Setting app?

Comment: Hi Tran Duc Tam. My problem is resolved. Thanks you so much!

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of how you finally fix it? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @joantoh why did not comment on main question thread?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/mailer
I'm using this for both Android/iOS. No issue on either of them.
It's a well maintained package.